# General principle to choose the location of a parameter (attribute) in a class

Tags: java, oop, object, design-patterns, interface

Could you talk to me a general principle to choose the location of a parameter (attribute) in a class?

For example, I can have a class:

```
class A {
     X x;
     Y y;
     A (X x, Y y) {...}
     void method() {...}
}
```

Way to use:

```
A a = new A(x, y);
a.method();
```

Or I can have a class:

```
class B {
     X x;
     B (X x) {...}
     void method(Y y) {...}
}
```

Way to use:

```
B b = new B(x);
b.method(y);
```

To rephrase the question: what should I incapsulating and what should I leave as part of the interface?

Comment: That entirely depends on your use case.

Comment: There are people out there making their money by inventing rules like that, but for this specific case I'm not aware of any. But maybe others are. Anybody?

Comment: I'd recommend reading Clean Code by Robert Martin. Objects and their functions should be expressive and readable.
The chapter on Refactoring SerialDate is great.

Comment: @JohnMitchell while Mr Martin dwells in creating rules, especially about comments, I'm not aware of any for this specific case.

Comment: So the answer your question receives is "it depends". For example; if your class should be immutable, then the variables should be final and provided to the constructor. If one variable is flexible, then it makes sense to receive it as method parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your class and its methods, you could choose the best pattern.

The important point for constructor is that:
Only mandatory parameters to create instance should be used in constructor.

For example, In your code, if `x` and `y` are just needed to use in `method`, putting them in constructor would make some issues. Before calling `method`, they could be changed in constructor. If you work in a team, other teammates could change the way of initialization of properties without knowing its negative impact on `method` function.